# __construct doesn't work in Controller laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to set some global variables with __construct, but it doesn't start, because I can write whatever into it and these functions didn't call any errors. I don't have City class in my app, but this code gives no error. Why?

/app/Http/Controller/Controller.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data['cities'] = City::get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? `public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); //Do Something more}`

Comment: there is no need to call parent::construct() in this code, there is no __construct in BaseController, it should give an error. Have you tried calling a function via a route on that controller? please show function code.

Comment: Any reason behind inheriting `Routing/Controller`

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn thanks for idea to check for a __construct() function in another controller which route is sending to. So I have two constructs, one in this controller, one in another. How to make work both of them, but this in example as a first one? Thanks!!

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn please post as an answer your question. I have added parent::__construct(); line at the end of another __construct function in another controller and now they both work.

Comment: @Gediminas Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your Constructor like this

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Because we need call parent Constructor first of alls.

Hope this help!